# Need to get the list from Option Vector

Tags: list, scala, vector, tuples, scala-option

I have a vector of option of List of Tuple 
like

```
val x = Vector(
Some(List(("x",2))),
Some(List(("x",2),("y",3))),
None,
Some(List(("x",2),("z",2))),
Some(List(("x",2),("z",2))),
None)
```

How to get the list from the above vector

Updated:

The final purpose is to get the total count of element in the list (we have three element only x or y or z).

like total count of x would return 8 and total count of y would return 3 and total count of z would return 4

like

```
val totalx = x.flatten.filter ....
```

Comment: Can you please provide proper code

Comment: And specification, what you're expecting together with your attempt would be nice

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a `Vector` here, and `some` doesn't compile. can you provide the valid code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i got the answer

```
x.flatten.flatten.filter(x => x._1 == "y").map(x => x._2).sum
```

used flatten to remove the none and then used flatten again to get all tuple flatten then filter and summing up

Answer (score 0):

```
x.flatMap {
  case Some(l) => l.filter(_._1=="x").map(_._2)
  case None => List(0)}.sum
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation how this solves the OP's problem. [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/3124333)

Comment: Yes - but it is pretty self-explanatory. Map over the outer list when there's a list map over that while filtering the needed tuples and taking their values, flatten the results, and sum the resulting list